# fill textbox which isn't inserted in FORM-tag in iframe

Tags: iframe, textbox, fill

I've got a question - i know how to fill in a text in a textbox which is in an iframe if there is the FORM-tag used. But what can i do if the textbox don't have the FORM tag? I've tried some code variations without success. Let's say the code looks like this:

```
  <tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="etext">Please enter your search string:</td></tr><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="formfieldpadding"><label><INPUT TYPE="TEXT"   id="text" class="formfield" NAME="pse_164_etext" VALUE="" ></label></td></tr><tr><td align="right" valign="top" class="buttonpadding"><input name="submit" type="image" src="/blah/button1.png" alt="Submit Button"  wcflags="IgnoreDBOCheck,TreatAsCDATA" style="width: 237px; height: 60px; border: none; padding-top: 0px;" /></td></tr>
```

How can i fill the VALUE of the textbox which is in my iframe ???? Would be REALLY glad if someone could help me, I mean REALLY! thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you'll face is that JavaScript is not allowed to access IFrame content from the parent window. This is a normal security restriction.

You can still bypass that by calling javascript FROM the Iframe. You can still access parent window from inside the IFrame:

```
parent.getElementById('text').value;
```

Comment: FROM iframe? where do i have to implement this code? i don't know how to implement a code WITHIN an iframe i just thought you can just enter the source and some characteristic attributes about it and that's it...but sounds like a great idea so far, thank u very much!

Comment: place `<script>` tag into the .html file which you load through `<iframe src=`

Comment: OK i've found an example like this:
`<iframe src="<script>document.write(foo());</script>"`

sry for my next stupid question but how can i specify my iframe source site then?! should i enter it just before/after the script tags?

Comment: no ,you need to point src towards a regular .html file and place the <script> inside that file. I'd suggest you to buy a book on JavaScript or study it online.

Comment: yeah that's why i waas asking mate. I've entered the source to the html file i want to iframe and in that html where the iframe is integrated, i've entered within the script tags `<script>


       function load() {
 
 parent.getElementById('text').value = 'searchthis';
   }
   window.onload = load;
</script>`

Still it doesn't work...sadly.. :(